# Split columns with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, multiple-columns

I have a Csv file with a one column and one raw. The column has 143 values(all numbers) and I want to split the column so that each value has its own column (i.e 143 columns)

How can I do that with Python?

so this is how it looks in the csv file. Number of visits represent days so 1 is Monday , 2 is Tuesday and so on.

```
ID             visits



34            12555566

I want to separate them so it looks like this 

ID      visits     0          1



34         1        2        5
```

The 0 and 1 are just column names.

Here's the code I'm using so far

```
 import pandas as pd
 file=pd.read_csv('trialtr.csv')

import calendar
days = list(calendar.day_name)

data = []
with open('trialtr.csv', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
     data.append(line.split())

data = dict(zip(*data))
d = {day: v for (day, v) in [(day,[int(c)]) for day, c in zip(days, 
data['visits'][1:])]}
d['ID'] = data['ID']
d['visits'] = data['visits'][0]
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I ended up getting this error :
"ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1000; 2 is required

Comment: Could you create an example with some values (not 143 please!) ?

Comment: the 143 values are separated by what? is it a list? a string separated by white-space?

Comment: they're not separated. they look like this 34545

Comment: The number of visits is always a single digit?

Comment: Are you trying to add additional col names apart from ID, visits.
And what do the second number signify? Is it a encoded set of values

Comment: @Yorian I updated the post

Comment: @AnoopToffy the 0 and 1 are just columns name.  What I'm trying to do is instead of having all the visits in one cell, I want to have each visit in a separate cell ( or column) the number of visits represents days so 1 means Sunday, 2 is Monday  and so on

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to convert you logic into code but this code will also convert your column value in row.

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
a = izip(*csv.reader(open("input.csv", "rb")))
csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb")).writerows(a)
```

Comment: Thanks , but does it work in python 3.6? I get this error" can't import name 'izip'

Comment: pip install izip

Comment: don't use izip in python3, just use zip

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
days = list(calendar.day_name)

data = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        data.append(line.split())

data = dict(zip(*data))
d = {day: v for (day, v) in [(day,[int(c)]) for day, c in zip(days, data['visits'][1:])]}
d['ID'] = data['ID']
d['visits'] = data['visits'][0]
data = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Edit**
Improved it slightly to get to a DataFrame with named columns for the days of the week. If you don't want that, just replace the days variable with range(7)

Nonetheless I think your idea doesn't work. What If you have 11 views on a day? And the first number in the visits column: shouldn't that be the sum of the total amount of visits (else why are there 8 numbers?)

Comment: thank you but I get " ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1000; 2 is required"

Comment: Works for me, but I don't have your source file. Also which python are you using?

Comment: So the days refer to the first day of the week in the course of 143 weeks. For example 234. In the first week customer visited on 2 which is Monday , the second week is 3 which means in the second week customer visited on Tuesday. I'm trying to extract into for example If I want to know on the third week week what was they day? third week would be the third column. I hope I'm making sense. I will update with the code I used

Comment: Maybe make the file available somehwere? So why didn't you seperate the columns with commas for example, would make this much easier